# Yii - Error (and possible solution) validating form with clientValidation active, and using a custom container

Tags: forms, validation, yii

I was creating a CActiveForm with the ClientValidation enabled, but stepped in an error when I wrapped a RadioButtonList inside a UL container.

Whenever I submited the form I get a "field cannot be empty" message, even if the radios were checked.

My form:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'id'=>'enrollment-form',
 'enableClientValidation'=>true,

 'clientOptions'=>array(
     'inputContainer'=>'ul',
     'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
 ),
));
```

And one of the RadioButtonLists I use:

```
<div id="drinks">
  <?php echo $form->label($model,'drink_id',array('class' => 'title')); ?>                
  <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'drink_id', CHtml::listData($drinks, 'id', 'name'), array('container'=>'ul', 'template' => '<li class="radio_row">{input}{label}</li>','separator' => '')); ?>                
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'drink_id'); ?>
</div>
```

Was I making something wrong?

I studied the code of the jquery.yiiactiveform.js and found that my problem was that in the function that gets the value of the inputs, the value was not taken correctly, because the ID used to identify the inputs was not set in a span, or in the checkboxes/radios themselves (the id was set in the UL container I defined):

```
var getAFValue = function (o) {
    var type,
        c = [];
    if (!o.length) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if (o[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span') {
        o.find(':checked').each(function () {
            c.push(this.value);
        });
        return c.join(',');
    }
    type = o.attr('type');
    if (type === 'checkbox' || type === 'radio') {
        return o.filter(':checked').val();
    } else {
        return o.val();
    }
};
```

So I solved this adding **|| o[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'ul'**:

```
var getAFValue = function (o) {
    var type,
        c = [];
    if (!o.length) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if (o[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span' || o[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'ul') {
        o.find(':checked').each(function () {
            c.push(this.value);
        });
        return c.join(',');
    }
    type = o.attr('type');
    if (type === 'checkbox' || type === 'radio') {
        return o.filter(':checked').val();
    } else {
        return o.val();
    }
};
```

Maybe I was just making some mistake and this solution is just a crappy workaround... but maybe this is just a bug ¿?

The HTML generated:

```
<form id="enrollment-form" action="/enrollment" method="post">
  <div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" value="b06e1d1d796f838f30ba130f8d990034aa9fdad6" name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN" /></div>    
  <div id="enrollment-form_es_" class="errorSummary" style="display:none"><p>Please fix the following input errors:</p>
    <ul><li>dummy</li></ul>
  </div>

  <div id="drinks">
    <label class="title" for="EnrollmentForm_drink_id">Drinks</label>                
    <input id="ytEnrollmentForm_drink_id" type="hidden" value="" name="EnrollmentForm[drink_id]" />

    <ul id="EnrollmentForm_drink_id">
      <li class="radio_row">
        <input id="EnrollmentForm_drink_id_0" value="2" type="radio" name="EnrollmentForm[drink_id]" />
        <label for="EnrollmentForm_drink_id_0">Tea</label>
      </li>
      <li class="radio_row">
        <input id="EnrollmentForm_drink_id_1" value="1" type="radio" name="EnrollmentForm[drink_id]" />
        <label for="EnrollmentForm_drink_id_1">Juice</label>
      </li>
    </ul>                
    <div class="errorMessage" id="EnrollmentForm_drink_id_em_" style="display:none"></div>
  </div>
```

I noticed that if I didn't use any container when generating the RadioButtonList, Yii aplies a "class=success" to a span. And with my UL container, that class is not generated. When I've changed the Javascript, the class success is generated again.

** The HTML generated without the inputContainer option and without the last array in radioButtonList:

```
<div id="drinks">
  <label class="title" for="EnrollmentForm_drink_id">Bebidas</label>                
  <input id="ytEnrollmentForm_drink_id" type="hidden" value="" name="EnrollmentForm[drink_id]">

  <span id="EnrollmentForm_drink_id">
    <input id="EnrollmentForm_drink_id_0" value="2" type="radio" name="EnrollmentForm[drink_id]"> <label for="EnrollmentForm_drink_id_0">Tea</label><br>
    <input id="EnrollmentForm_drink_id_1" value="1" type="radio" name="EnrollmentForm[drink_id]"> <label for="EnrollmentForm_drink_id_1">Juice</label>
  </span>                
 <div class="errorMessage" id="EnrollmentForm_drink_id_em_" style="display:none"></div>            
</div>
```

As you can see, Yii generates a strange span that controls if the form is valid or not, by aplying to it the class "success". If I use the inputContainer UL then this class="success" is not generated (with my workaround it is generated and it works).

Comment: What does the generated html look like?

Comment: Added the HTML generated and some other explanation.

Comment: What does the HTML look like when you remove `inputContainer` from `clientOptions`, and the last array from `radioButtonList`?

Comment: Added the HTML. The main problem is that with the inputContainer, Yii does not aply class="success" to the <ul>.